# Mongod does not start (mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal')

Tags: linux, mongodb, debian

After command `sudo service mongod start && sudo service mongod status`

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Wed 2021-08-18 11:58:29 MSK; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 13899 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=killed, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 13899 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

авг 18 11:58:29 400sk systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
авг 18 11:58:29 400sk systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=4/ILL
авг 18 11:58:29 400sk systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
```

Does **not write logs** in /var/logs

Debian 10, try MongoDB 4.2 and 5.0, Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5540  @ 2.53GHz

Installation from official site (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signal "ILL" is illegal instruction.

MongoDB 5.0 requires Advanced Vector Extensions, Xeon E5540 does not have them.

For a list of processors that support AVX, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX

Comment: Thank you, problem solved. I mistakenly thought I was working with version 4.2

Comment: how to fix this issue? Can you tell the detail?

Comment: @Nikita Demckenko So this issue can not fix? Can you share the solution? Thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `libmkl-dev` and `lib-avx2` are installed and available on your OS. On Debian 10, these packages are in Nonfree amd64 repository. Add the repo to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` Enable the repo then do `apt-get` update followed by:

```
apt-get install libmkl-dev libmkl-avx2 mongodb-org
```