# Mongodb after install crash

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, vmware

i'm trying to start fresh installed mongodb

(packets  mongodb-org=5.0.2 mongodb-org-database=5.0.2 mongodb-org-server=5.0.2 mongodb-org-shell=5.0.2 mongodb-org-mongos=5.0.2 mongodb-org-tools=5.0.2)

- OS ubuntu20.04 (clear, fresh installed)
- Vmware exsi
- config default

and after install i'm trying start service ang get errors like that:

sudo systemctl status mongod.service

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Mon 2021-11-22 13:02:15 UTC; 1s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 1769 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 1769 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Nov 22 13:02:14 rocket systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 22 13:02:15 rocket systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Nov 22 13:02:15 rocket systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

journal -xe:

```
-- A start job for unit mongod.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 456.
Nov 22 12:59:33 rocket sudo[1687]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Nov 22 12:59:33 rocket kernel: show_signal: 18 callbacks suppressed
Nov 22 12:59:33 rocket kernel: traps: mongod[1693] trap invalid opcode ip:562c4fb0708a sp:7ffe3d3abcb0 error:0 in mongod[562c4bbc8000+5055000]
Nov 22 12:59:34 rocket systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mongod.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'dumped' and its exit status is 4.
Nov 22 12:59:34 rocket systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit mongod.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'core-dump'.
```

> rocket kernel: traps: mongod[1693] trap invalid opcode ip:562c4fb0708a
> sp:7ffe3d3abcb0 error:0 in mongod[562c4bbc8000+5055000]

limits:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47570
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47570
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongod does not start (mongod.service: Failed with result 'signal')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829656/mongod-does-not-start-mongod-service-failed-with-result-signal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. the issue looks to be a matter of missing dependencies.
Run:

`apt-get -u dist-upgrade`

and then reinstall mongodb

b.  Dont use 5.0.2 - it has a severe alert from MongoDB for that version.

Use 5.0.3 instead

Comment: it’s now working. I think, it’s a problem with legacy CPU, and proc instructions. im fixed issue with downgrade to 4.4 version, but u solution work for modern systems )

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Mongo is sensitive to extensions on the underlying chipset (AVX). If you are running this under KVM, you have to experiment with the underlying CPU
architecture. I had the same problem with Mongo 6.0.4.

I am running KVM on an older Xeon chip, so instead of QEMU emulation, I pass execution to the underlying processor. All is well then.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodb-5-0-cpu-intel-g4650-compatibility/116610

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you did this (instead of QEMU emulation, I pass execution to the underlying processor) ?

Comment: @ClaudioKuenzler  I use Cockpit to manage the KVM machines that run on the host. The GUI has the emulation type set. I believe you can set that using some virtsh commands. Here is the discussion of those possible choices. https://qemu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/system/qemu-cpu-models.html  I have run into this problem several times on different VMs that I run. I was not surprised.