# mongodb.service: Failed with result 'core-dump' in Arch Linux

Tags: mongodb, coredump

I have a problem starting mongodb. I use Arch Linux and i have installed **mongodb-bin** from AUR but when i start mongodb and check status it shows core-dump error. Please give me the solution. Error code message is given below.

[azzyy@arch ~]$ mongo
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
[azzyy@arch ~]$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
× mongodb.service - MongoDB Database Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2021-11-27 10:46:35 IST; 35min ago
Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
Process: 6689 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
Main PID: 6689 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
CPU: 50ms

Nov 27 10:46:34 arch systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwm9y.jpg): Started MongoDB Database Server.
Nov 27 10:46:35 arch systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwm9y.jpg): mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Nov 27 10:46:35 arch systemd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwm9y.jpg): mongodb.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'

[Screenshot of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwm9y.jpg)

Comment: `Illegal instruction` means the CPU can't run that.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830728/2282634

Answer (score 0):

that's not a problem your cpu might be too old to support the standard library
you should use the alternate aur package provided
https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mongodb44-bin/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).