# What version of mongoDB do I need to run on a rasberrypi 4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to install and run mongoDB on my raspberrypi 4 so I can host a project on it. I installed mongoDB following their own [tutorial](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-on-raspberry-pi/). The problem is when I run and get the status I get these errors:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2023-02-28 12:47:29 UTC; 2s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 14290 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
   Main PID: 14290 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)

Feb 28 12:47:28 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 28 12:47:29 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=4/ILL
Feb 28 12:47:29 ubuntu systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.
```

Ive done some research and ensured I was using the 64bit version of ubuntu. I also read somewhere that this is most likely caused by the cpu not meeting certain requirements (Rasberrypi4 uses the Broadcom BCM2711 quad core Cortex-A72 processor). But they said this applied to versions 5.0+ but ive tried running 4.4 and 4.3. Since Ive seen people run it I am wondering what version of mongoDB do I need to install to be able to run it on the rasberrypi4?

Comment: Have a look at the mongo logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit not really sure what I am looking for. Theres a couple warnings about using the XFS filesystem with WiredTiger and then access control is not enabled. But the it just shuts down with signal 15 and says terminated

Comment: Look for errors, see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/log-messages/

Comment: The error is 'illegal instructrion' `signal=ILL`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68829656/mongod-does-not-start-mongod-service-failed-with-result-signal

Comment: MongoDB does not currently support Raspberry Pi binaries. If you want to use a recent release, I have built the community edition myself and put them on [Github](https://github.com/themattman/mongodb-raspberrypi-binaries). Feel free to raise an issue on the repo if they are not working. I am running a 6.2 instance on a Raspberry Pi 4 at the moment.